# Mysqli_fetch_array not giving any results

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm working on a website that uses a lot of database echoing.
But the problem is I have used some code that always worked for me before and this time it isn't working at all.

The Code:

```
<?php
    $result=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM action ORDER BY gameid ASC");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $row['gamename'];
    }
?>
```

I am not seing any errors.

Comment: What exactly is in `$mysqli`?

Comment: The mysqli_connect() stuff

Comment: Does the query give you any results when you run it directly in your db?

Comment: add `mysqli_query() or die($mysqli->error)` and check whats up

Comment: Its not giving any results but ill try the error thingy

Comment: Then it may be a connection problem, in $mysqli definition

Comment: Show your `$mysqli` connect stuff

Comment: $host   =  "sql305.freezoy.com";
 $user   =  "(or this)";
 $pass   =  "(not giving this)";
 $daba   =  "frzoy_16044062_game";
 
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $daba);

Comment: Try to check the result: `if ($result === FALSE) echo "I got no results for you."; else echo "Well, there is something here.";`.

Comment: Its not showing the echo

Comment: Try the 'else' bit. Still nothing? Then you might have a syntax error somewhere.

Comment: that gives me a result

Comment: Are you getting `gamename`

Comment: im getting nothing out of the original echo but the else KIKO suggested is being displayed

Comment: Then try to run your query within `sql` or try **error_reporting(E_ALL)**  which will show if there's an error

Comment: Within the loop try `print_r($row);` to see what's in the rows, this will only do something if there are rows to display.

Comment: Nothing i even added a 2nd fake game to the db and its doing nothing

Comment: I guess you mean with the `print_r()`? I'm sorry, I cannot explain it. You've check that it has a result, there's no syntax error, and you should get the two rows in the database. You could still check this with: `echo '['.mysqli_num_rows($result).']';` just after the query and before the loop.

Comment: Chasing the _Excavator_ / _Archaeologist_ badges @Dharman? 

Comment: @Phil No, just stuck in an everlasting rabbit hole. I search one thing and I get hundreds of nonsensical posts that need to be closed, retagged or/and deleted. If you want to help out I appreciate any help I can get. Thanks

Comment: @Dharman I'm just foolin'. Keep up the good work 

Answer (score -1):

try maybe it helps

```
$result=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM action ORDER BY gameid ASC");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)
echo $row['gamename'];
```

Comment: this did not help im thinking its something wrong with the database